# jQuery run onclick function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I execute this function only one time?
I tried `.one` but it doesn't work

```
$('a.inspire-tag').on('click',function () {         
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".button-inspire").offset().top
    }, 400);
});
```

Comment: `.one()` handler is executed at most once per element per event type. Do you have multiple elements `'a.inspire-tag'`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly ?

Comment: Have you tried $(this).off() inside your click function?

Comment: .one() seems to work fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/F3E47/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.inspire-tag').on('click',doThis);
function doThis () {         
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".button-inspire").offset().top
    }, 400);
    //you can off all on callback function
    $('a.inspire-tag').off('click',doThis);
}
```

Comment: You certainly want `doThis` without parens `()` when submitting it as a click handler, or the function will be invoked right on spot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do is just click once to enable

Try this:

```
$('a.inspire-tag').on('click',function () {         
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".button-inspire").offset().top
    }, 400);
    $('a.inspire-tag').off('click');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/), with name spaced [event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

```
$('a.inspire-tag').on('click.myevent', function () {
    if (...)
    // remove current event handler
    $(this).off('click.myevent')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oneTime = true;
$('a.inspire-tag').on('click',function () {         
    if(oneTime) {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(".button-inspire").offset().top
        }, 400);
        oneTime = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @carambly, yes this works, but we can use off or one also in Jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var inspiretag = $('a.inspire-tag');
inspiretag.on('click',function () {         
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".button-inspire").offset().top
    }, 400);
inspiretag.off('click');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/